# How to use git diff to only diff .cs files

Tags: git

I tried to diff only .cs files, I use:
git diff HEAD -- ./*.cs
It just didn't work. Note there are several cs files under different directories.
What is the correct command?

Thanks!

---

I use msysgit in windows. I decided to write a python script for it. Here it is:

```
import os
screenOutput = os.popen('git status').read()
lines =screenOutput.splitlines()
keyword = 'modified:'
cmd = 'git diff HEAD -- '
for line in lines:
    index = line.find(keyword)
    if(index >= 0):
        line = line[index + len(keyword) + 1:].strip()
        if(line.endswith('.cs')):
            cmd += (line + ' ')
os.system(cmd)
```

The script captures the 'git status' output, searches the line with the keyword 'modified:', and gets the modified file names. It's ugly. But it works. And it can be extended to handle arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I might try `git diff HEAD -- $(find . -name '*.cs')` so that you're giving it the full paths to each. Not sure if that will work, but it might do the trick.

Comment: If you are trying to do this for git diff head~5 head, it will not find any .cs files that were deleted before head and match the pattern you want.

Comment: That's an excellent point. A more complete answer would probably involve some kind of shell script that parses `git log` and gets the diff targets that way. The question seemed to be more along the lines of "find all unstaged/uncommitted .cs files and show the diffs", so that's what my answer leans towards

Answer (score 2):

`git diff HEAD -- "*.cs"` should work.

Comment: @MattBusche Note that the command I suggested is slightly different from the command in the OP.

Comment: @MattBusche Also note that I just edited my answer, but the command I suggest is still slightly different than the OP.

Answer (score 1):

`git diff **/*.cs` did it for me.

Comment: This is probably bash 4 specific, as the `**` glob was only added then. It should work in zsh though.

Comment: This does not work in MSysGit on windows. Their implementation of bash is equivalent to something earlier than bash 4.

Comment: Ah, well. I use zsh which supports globs in file paths. That might explain why it does not work with msysgit and older Bash-based shells.